# Jordan canonical form and basis for 4 by 4 matrix with two eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

So, I am given the matrix in standard basis
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&3&3\\-10&2&9&9\\-4&0&5&4\\2&1&-3&-2\end{bmatrix}$$
characteristic polynomial is $(λ−1)^3 (λ+1)$ which means eigenvalues are $λ_1= 1$, with multiplicity $3$, and $λ_2= -1$, with multiplicity $1$. How should I go about obtaining the Jordan canonical form and basis of said matrix? I tried calculating the rank of the matrix $A-1\times\operatorname I$, and determining using that, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your first step is fine. What did you find the rank of $A - I$ to be? This is indeed enough information to find the Jordan form; from there you can find the basis.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I calculated that rank of A - I is 2. I think that the jordan canonical form should be $$Ae =\begin{bmatrix}1&?&0&0\\0&1&?&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ and then using rank(A-I)=rank(Ae-I)=2 I should put 1 and 0 in such way that the statement stays valid, but I'm not sure how to correctly put the 0 and 1 where the ? are, it seems there are two ways and I'm not sure how to determine the right one.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your issue a bit further. The answer is that both placements are correct; just as one can arrange the eigenvalues in any order for diagonalization, one can arrange the three Jordan blocks at play in any order. The two placements that you are considering correspond to
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
1\\
\hline
&1&1\\
&&1\\
\hline
&&&-1
\end{array}
\right],
\qquad 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
1&1\\
&1\\
\hline
&&1\\
\hline
&&&-1
\end{array}
\right],
$$
which are both valid arrangements of the Jordan blocks

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that $v_1=(0,-3,-2,3)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $-1$ and the the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is
$$
E_1=\{(a+b,a+b,a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\},
$$
which is two-dimensional. Now, let us look for a vector $v=(x,y,z,t)$ such that $A.v=v+w$, for some $w\in E_1$. Note that
$$
A.v-v=(-4x+y+3z+3t,-10x+y+9z+9t,-4x+4z+4t,2x+y-3z-3t).
$$
In order to determine when such a vector belongs to $E_1$, we can solve the system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}-4x+y+3z+3t=-4x+4z+4t+2x+y-3z-3t\\-10x+y+9z+9t=-4x+4z+4t+2x+y-3z-3t.\end{array}\right.
$$
One non-zero solution of this system is $(0,1,0,0)$, and $A.(0,1,0,0)=(0,1,0,0)+(1,1,0,1)$. So:

- let $v_2=(1,1,0,1)(\in E_1)$;
- let $v_3=(0,1,0,0)$;
- let $v_4=(1,1,1,0)(\in E_1)$.

With these choices for the $v_i$'s, we have:

- $A.v_1=-v_1$;
- $A.v_2=v_2$;
- $A.v_3=v_3+v_2$;
- $A.v_4=v_4$.

So, if
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&1\\-3&1&1&1\\-2&0&0&1\\3&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
(the columns of $P$ are $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, and $v_4$), then
$$
P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$